# AKS K8S - access spring-boot app from angular frontend using service name

Tags: angular, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have two application frontend developed using angular and backend developed using spring-boot. Both the app are running in same namespace.

Already created two service of type: Loadbalancer.

1. frontend say `frontend-app-lb` (exposed 9001)
2. backend say `backend-app-lb` (exposed 9000).

I am able to get the response with the External Ip. using curl `http://<External-ip>:900[0/1]/`

In angular app, i configured environment-prod.ts, with baseurl as `http://<External-ip-of-backend-app-lb>:9000/`. With the CORS allowed, able to access the backend app.

I also know that, if the app is running in different namespace, we can access the application/pod from different namespace, using this `http://<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:port`.

How to access the backend app running in the same namespace just using the service name in baseurl like `http://backend-app-lb:9000`. - Is this possible?

Comment: Where do you want to connect from ?
If `backend-app-lb` is the name of the Service, you should be able to resolve this name from inside another Pod using e.g. `nslookup  backend-app-lb` .

Comment: Connect.from another pod running within the same namespace..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found out, accessing `http://backend-app-lb:9000` might not be a approach to do it.

Other approaches:

Approach #1: Using Azure application gateway:

- Expose the backend service a LoadBalancer type service, (in my case the applications deployed in AKS). So a Application Gateway (Layer 7) was configured.

  - say any url `/backend-api` connect to the backend application.
- In frontend application `environment.prod.ts`, use the `/backend-api` as baseurl to connect to the backend api.

Approach #2: Using Nginx proxy

- If the frontend application is developed on Ngnix server, using the configuration the we create a proxy and access the backend service.
- Reference available at [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/)
- In this case the backend application can be exposed as service (it can be of type NodePort or LoadBalancer).

Both approach, in a way makes the Frontend application access to the backend service simple and no need for manipulation during build.