# Angular to pass the baseURL in the environment.ts file at deploy time

Tags: angular, kubernetes

I have an Angular app where the `environment.ts` file is hard coded with the `baseURL` like below. The backend service is also deployed in same cluster and accessible with a service name.

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseURL: 'http://<service>.<namespace>:<port>/api/v1/'
  ...
}
```

Currently the URL is hardcode in `environemnt.ts` and the image is built using Dockerfile.

Say, If I want to use the image and deploy as Kubernetes deployment, is there a way to pass this `baseURL` in the manifest during runtime or dynamically? Note, trying to deploy httpd server not Nginx.

Comment: The way we solve this is by serving our Angular apps with Node, passing the values for the environment in to be interpolated when the index.html is rendered, and setting the values into sessionStorage on the browser. Our Angular apps have an environment service that picks these values up and provides them where needed. The environment values are set via Terraform, but anything that sets a `process.env` value will also work. This way you can deploy a single codebase across any environment.

Comment: Dont use environment.ts in the first place as it works fine when you build your app, but not when you actually try to use the same codebase on different environments (as you have figured out yourself)

Comment: The better approach is to use Gateway configured and load balancer type service. - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66392001/3192775)

Comment: @Tim especially for localhost, staging, prod where EVERYTHING can be literally different ;)

Comment: I've covered various options for this [on my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html) - build-time configuration like Angular's environment file simply don't work in a lot of practical cases.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use environment.ts in the first place as it works fine when you build your app, but not when you actually try to use the same codebase on different environments (as you have figured out yourself).

What I did in a past was to use some sort of tokens in the `environment.ts` eg

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseURL: 'BASE_URL'
  ...
}
```

and then during the deployment I was literally replacing `BASE_URL` in the `main.js` file with `sed`. Its not ideal, even kind of bad, but it worked just fine as you expected.

Another way would be to externalize your config to a separate file that will be placed next to the deployment, eg `env.js`. Such file can be served as any other parts of your application, therfore on the bootstrap you will be able to fetch it and provide via "configuration service" of your design.